# ¿Cómo realizo un prototype sin usar prototype?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo realizar la siguiente función y no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: ¿No sabes cómo hacerlo o no entiendes el enunciado? La solución es muy simple.

Comment: @Mateo No sé cómo hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que ejecutar la función que te pasan como parámetro por cada elemento. Te quedaría algo así:

```
Array.prototype.mapear = function(fun) {
    let nuevoArray = []
    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let elementoModificado = fun(this[i])
        nuevoArray.push(elementoModificado)
    }
    return nuevoArray
}
```